# Emacs: automatically enable Zen Coding mode

Tags: emacs, emmet

How to automatically enable [Zen Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding) mode (`zencoding-mode`) everytime I open an HTML file in Emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually use any of these, but something like this ought to do the trick:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook (lambda () (zencoding-mode 1)))
```

[edited to promote phils's comment to the answer]

Comment: Result: Toggling zencoding-mode off; better pass an explicit argument.

Comment: `(add-hook 'html-mode-hook (lambda () (zencoding-mode 1)))`